# Function that intentionally bleeds variables into caller's scope

Tags: python, variables, scope, metaprogramming

I have a function `P()`. A call to `load_variables()` should give `P` the variable `x`.
`load_variables`should be able to accept defaults as keyword arguments.

How can this be done?

I have tried the following:

```
import inspect
def P():
    x = 1
    load_variables(x = 2)
    return x

def load_variables(**kargs):
    stack = inspect.stack()
    try:
        locals_ = stack[1][0].f_locals
    finally:
        del stack
    for __k, __v in kargs.iteritems():
        locals_[__k] = __v

print P() # => should print 2
```

The `x = 1` line shouldn't actually be there, as I want `load_variables()` to just bleed the `x` into `P`'s scope.

Is there another, perhaps better, way to do this? What I want is:

1. Variables have a default value, e.g. `x = 2` in the above call to `load_variables()`.
2. I can overwrite these in `load_variables`, for instance, `load_varibales()` has access to a dictionary of variables, and if `x` is already here, we overwrite it, and spill this `x` instead of the one given as default argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python compiler and bytecode interpreter handles, where possible, references to local variables as slots into a defined-size array.  This means that if a local variable is not initialised (assigned to) in a scope then the language will not know that a slot for the variable exists in the scope, and will instead look for the variable in an enclosing scope or the global scope.  Looking at a disassembly of the function `P`:

```
def P():
    load_variables(x=2)
    return x

dis.dis(P)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (load_variables)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION          256
             12 POP_TOP             

  3          13 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that without an assignment to `x` in local scope `P` will look for it in global scope.

The right way to do this is to explicitly state which variables you expect the `load_variables` function to return, using unpacking:

```
x, y, z = load_variables(...)
```

Comment: How can i guarantee that the order of arguments is the same as when I return them? E.g. returning like @Mohammad Ali writes, `print load_variables(x = 2, y = 4, z = 10)` is returned as `{'y': 4, 'x': 2, 'z': 10}`

Comment: @MadsOhmLarsen you'll have to return them as `return x, y, z`.

Comment: The keyword arguments is a dict, so it shouldn't care about order, which is why I get the mixed return above. Is it possible to get the order in which they are input to `load_variables` so that I can in fact return an unknown number of keyword arguments in the same order?

Comment: @MadsOhmLarsen sorry, no, there's no ordering on a `**kwargs` argument.  You'll have to take arguments as literals `load_variables(('x', 2), ('y', 4), ('z', 10))`.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: as DSM pointed below, updating `locals()` is not supported. So, the answer is incorrect, at least for CPython.

<strike>Can you make `load_variables()` returns a dictionary and use `locals()` to update the local variables:</strike>

```
def P():
    x=1
    locals().update(load_variables(x=2))
    return x

def load_variables(**kargs):
    res={}
    for __k, __v in kargs.iteritems():
        res[__k] = __v
    return res
```

<strike>Note that `x=1` is required or otherwise `x` will be assumed a global variable by the bytecode compiler and you will get `NameError` exception for `return x`</strike>

If you really want to get rid of `x=1` you can us `retrun locals()['x']` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work: you can't update the `locals` dict this way, as the [docs warn](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals).  `P` returns 1 for me in CPython and PyPy, and 2 in IronPython, for implementation-dependent reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Since we're talking about Python here, there is probably a way to do it but I wonder: Should you try?

Usually, it's much better to define a shared storage/value object and then pass that around:

```
data = {}

def P(data):
     load_variables(data, x=2)
     return data['x']

def load_variables(data, **kargs):
     data.update(kargs)
```

That way, you won't have unforseen side effects.

Comment: +1 the idea of "bleeding" into an superior scope seemed kinda bloody